# What will happen if I deny Winter Bash access to my information?

Tags: support, profile-page, winter-bash

I noticed that  in [the profile's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) Edit Profile & Settings there is "Applications" section with this:

> [image]

It does say:

> Remove an application to remove access to your information.

But it's not very clear what it actually means. So, if I remove Winter Bash, will it...

1. cause it to just stop working for me?
2. be the same as "I hate hats"?
3. Is this reversible?

I prefer not to try it myself just to test, because I rather love hats. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only thing that's being used for is logging in on http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/. The first time you clicked "log in" on that site (or on one of its predecessors in the previous years), you confirmed that you want to let the site know who you are. On subsequent logins you no longer had to confirm this because once you have authorized the app, this is being remembered.

If you removed it, nothing would happen immediately – the only difference would be that the next time you log in to the Winter Bash site (possibly after logging out before), you'd have to do an extra click again to re-authorize the site to know who you are.

I've updated the app's description to make that clear.